# Find Content By Permalink from the Backend

Tags: orchardcms

Is there an easy way to find a Content by permalink from the admin panel ?

I have a website with thousands of Content's, and whenever I'm asked : I need a change to this page : domain.com/route I have to spend ages to find the corresponding Content by paginating through countless pages. It seems too wrong to be the only way to do it.

Any alternative ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well typically you can index the pages and enable admin search to quickly search what you need.

But you can also add edit button directly to frontend to allow for quick editting.

```
if (Authorizer.Authorize(Permissions.EditContent))
{
    @Html.ActionLink(T("Edit page").ToString(), "Edit", "Admin", new { Model.ContentItem.Id, Area = "Contents", ReturnUrl = Context.Request.RawUrl }, new { @class = "editButtonClass" })
}
```

1. Find file **Core/Contents/Views/Content.cshtml**
2. Copy it to your theme's view folder (if you want edit link to appear only for content type "Page" then rename this file in your theme's folder to **Content-Page.cshtml**
3. Open the copy in text editor and place the above code anywhere you like it to appear
4. Restart your site so override is applied
5. Now if you have edit permission, all pages will have "Edit page" link on them. Click it and you are taken to editing their content in administration. Once you hit "Publish" you are returned back to frontend with notification "Your Page has been saved."

Comment: Or you can just enable the Content Control Wrapper feature